# variable php in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Need  variable php in blade laravel - value input, variable $i to for
add the value of $i, within the value = "{ {$ tarefa->etapa. $i }}

---

to do so: value = "{{ $tarefa->etapa1 }}
value = "{{ $tarefa->etapa2 }} ... to 10

```
@php
    $now = 0;
    $last = 10; @endphp
    @for ($i = $now; $i < $last; $i++)
    <div class="col-sm-6">                      
    <input id="etapa" class="form-syle" name="etapa1"  value="{{ $tarefa->etapa**@variable php** }}  ">
    </div>
    @endfor
```

Comment: Could you share some more snippets of code, and try to explain your problem more elaborately.

Comment: add the value of $i, within the value = "{ {$ tarefa->etapa. $i }}

to do so:

value = "{{ $tarefa->etapa1 }}
value = "{{ $tarefa->etapa2 }}
... 
to 10

Answer (score 1):

You can put the name of the attribute you need into a string.

```
$attributeName = 'etapa'.$i;

<input id="etapa" class="form-syle" name="etapa1"  value="{{ $tarefa->$attributeName }}  ">
```